# store pk from detail route in the serializer [django REST API]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I asked this question before but with less clarity**

How to save the `id` inside the `RelatedFiled` of the `ForeignKey` ?

I am testing an application on django, I have two models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_id = models.IntegerField()
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=260)


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='song', blank=True, null=True)    #foreign key
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length=260)
```

with `Song` containing a foreign key to `Album`

My question is how do I store automatically the `pk` or `id` of `album` inside that foreign key ?

I have set up a `detail_route` , and when I print `album_id` I get the correct one that I am trying to access in the url

for example: `album/101/song` will print `album_id` as 101. But in my serializer it is not saving the RelatedField as 101. How do I fix this ?

```
    @detail_route(methods=['post', 'get'], serializer_class=SongSerialiser)
    def get_so(self, request, album_id=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, context={"album_id": album_id })
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print album_id # this works !
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"detail": serializer.errors,
                             "status_code": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
```

**Serializer**:

```
class SongSerialiser(serializers.Serializer):
    album = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    song_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        album_id = self.context.get("album_id")
        print album_id   # I expect this to print 101 or the related id
        instance = Song.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out inside the serializer I need to use:

```
self.context.get("request").parser_context["kwargs"]["album_id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `album_id` in `context`, you can **pass `album_id` via `serializer.save()`** and DRF will automatically create `Song` object with `album_id` field.

You need to make some changes to your code.

In your views, you don't need to pass `context` to the serializer. You should instead pass `album_id` in `serializer.save()`.

```
@detail_route(methods=['post', 'get'], serializer_class=SongSerialiser)
def get_so(self, request, album_id=None):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(album_id=album_id) # pass album_id here
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({"detail": serializer.errors,
                         "status_code": status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST})
```

Secondly, you can convert `SongSerialiser` to `ModelSerializer` having only the field `song_name` without adding the `create()` method.

```
class SongSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer): # use modelserializer

    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ['song_name'] # only define song_name field
```

When `serializer.save()` is called, DRF will create `Song` object with `song_name` from `request.data` and `album_id` from extra kwarg we passed in `.save()`.